# Why is the coefficient of static friction usually different from the coefficient of kinetic friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, kinematics, friction

Why is the coefficient of static friction, <sub>s</sub>, usually different from the coefficient of kinetic friction, <sub>k</sub>?

On Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction) it says that usually <sub>s</sub> is greater than <sub>k</sub> - why is it the case?